# Is there any tangible downside to using static type constructors in go?

Tags: go

I've always found the package.New() syntax in go rather awkward to work with.

The suggestion is that if a package holds only a single type, using package.New() to create an instance; if multiple types exist, using package.NewBlah(). 
http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names

However, this approach falls down if you if you have an existing package with a New() api, adding a new external type to the package breaks the api, because you must now rename this NewFoo(). Now you have to go and change anything that uses New(), which is deeply irritating.

...and I'm just discontent with the aesthetic of writing this:

```
import "other"
import "bar"
import "foo"

o := other.New()  // <-- Weird, what type am I getting? No idea.
x := bar.New()  
y := foo.NewFoo() // <-- Awkward, makes constructor naming look inconsistent   
z := foo.NewBar()
```

So, recently I've been using this pattern instead:

```
x := foo.Foo{}.New()   // <-- Immediately obvious I'm getting a Foo
y := foo.Bar{}.New()   // <-- Only an additional 3 characters on NewBar{}
o := other.Foo{}.New() // <-- Consistent across all packages, no breakage on update
```

Where the module is defined something like this:

```
package foo

type Foo struct {
  x int
}

func (s Foo) New() *Foo {
  // Normal init stuff here
  return &s // <-- Edit: notice the single instance is returned 
}

type Bar struct {
}

func (Bar) New() *Bar {
  return &Bar{} // <-- Edit: Bad, results in double alloc. Not like this. 
}
```

Godoc seems to work fine with it, and it seems more obvious and consistent to me, without additional verbosity.

So, question: **Is there any tangible downside to this?**

Comment: I guess its just a matter of opinion but a package called foo that can constructs foo's and bar's seems like the only contrived example that would be made cleaner by your modified approach.  Wouldn't a well named package remove any doubt what `New` would return?

Comment: Come on, you see this *all* the time in real packages. It's totally not a contrived example.

Comment: grep "func.* New[A-Z]" * -R | wc on the go code base; there are 151 instances in the core libraries *alone*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't trying to be critical, I was just suggesting that this approach might solve one type of package structure but not a more "go style" of code organization. One of the stated goals of the language is to minimize typing of redundant data. If this works for you than +1, I am also interested if there other implications by this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has a downside. This approach may generate unnecessary garbage - depending on how good the optimization of a specific Go compiler implementation  is.

Comment: Can you explain that? I don't understand.

Comment: Two instances of foo.Foo{} exist on entering foo.Foo.New() by foo.Foo{}.New() and one becomes unreachable.

Comment: This is only true if the New() function is stupid an returns a new instance (as in my examples, my bad). See the new Foo.New() function above; this avoids that issue.

Comment: No, the New() method already works on an unnecessarily copied instance, which is its receiver.

Answer (score 2):

It's not terribly idiomatic and may if done badly create excess garbage as you note. Essentially you are just creating an Init method for your object. I don't use a lot of constructors myself tending to prefer having valid zero values for my objects and only using a constructor if that doesn't hold true.

In your case I think I'd just stop calling the method new and instead call it Init or Setup to better reflect what it's doing. That would avoid giving people the wrong idea about what it's doing.

Edit:

I should have been more detailed here. Calling the method Init or Setup and then using it on a Zero Value would better reflect what is going on to the consumer. eg

```
f := &foo{}
f.Init()
```

This avoids the excess garbage and gives you an initializer method as you describe.

Comment: Is a side effect of this a problem in that you can call `Foo{}.New().New().New()`? seen here http://play.golang.org/p/cea2KhaQuH (I'm still learning Go)

Comment: The excesive creation of garbage is guaranteed in the OP - not only if done badly. Every foo.Foo{} creates a new instance, which is then passed by value (copied) to .New() and the thrown away. It's not that it should be named Init/Setup etc. It's a plain wrong practice.

Comment: You are right I should have been more detailed in my answer. I've modified it to better reflect what I meant.